# Type contract campaign is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, remix

While trying to create and store address of a newly created solidity contract:

```
address newCampaign = new Campaign();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Type contract Campaign is not implicitly convertible to expected type address
```

Answer (score 5):

The address needs to be explicity converted:

```
address newCampaign = address(new Campaign());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign();
```

if you want to get the smart contract address

```
newCamPaign.address
```